# Python Pandas get grouped data rate

Tags: python, pandas

I have such a problem i have year grouped data:

```
com_name     year   type  value
company1     2000   A      100
company1     2000   B      600
company1     2001   A      900
company2     2005   B      300
company2     2000   A      687
company2     2000   B      989
company3     2015   A      351
company3     2015   B      654
company3     2016   B      9345
```

And for each company for each year i need to have A/B ratio

```
com_name  year   type  value    type ratio
company1  2000   A      100        1/7
company1  2000   B      600        6/7
company1  2001   A      900         1
company2  2005   B      300         1 
company2  2000   A      600        6/15
company2  2000   B      900        9/15
company3  2015   A      300        3/9
company3  2015   B      600        6/9
company3  2016   B      9345        1
```

so type ratio column = value type A / (value type B + value type A) for each company for each year.

type_ratio type should be float, not common fraction. I use it just for sample

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `sum` for new `Series` filled by aggregate values and divide by original column:

```
#if necessary convert to column comp
df = df.rename_axis('comp').reset_index()
print (df)
       comp  year type  value
0  company1  2000    A    100
1  company1  2000    B    600
2  company1  2001    A    900
3  company2  2005    B    300
4  company2  2010    A    687
5  company2  2010    B    989
6  company3  2015    A    351
7  company3  2015    B    654
8  company3  2016    B   9345

df['ratio'] = df['value'].div(df.groupby(['comp','year'])['value'].transform('sum'))
print (df)
       comp  year type  value     ratio
0  company1  2000    A    100  0.142857
1  company1  2000    B    600  0.857143
2  company1  2001    A    900  1.000000
3  company2  2005    B    300  1.000000
4  company2  2010    A    687  0.409905
5  company2  2010    B    989  0.590095
6  company3  2015    A    351  0.349254
7  company3  2015    B    654  0.650746
8  company3  2016    B   9345  1.000000
```

Comment: tranks a lot for your answer, but how to solve this issue if companies not a index?

Comment: @Xum3abodMedia - Not sure if understand, `company` values are important here?

Comment: yes, ratio should be calculated for each company for each year